# Index words by line number from text file

Tags: python, dictionary, text, indexing, python-3.4

So my homework question is to have function `lineIndex` index words from a text file and return the list of line numbers for each word in the text file. The whole output has to be returned in a dictionary.

For example here is what it is in the text file:

```
I have no pride
I have no shame
You gotta make it rain
Make it rain rain rain`
```

My professor wants the output to look like this:

```
{'rain': [2, 3], 'gotta': [2], 'make': [2], 'it': [2, 3], 'shame': [1], 'I': [0, 1], 'You': [2], 'have': [0, 1], 'no': [0, 1], 'Make': [3], 'pride': [0]}
```

For example: the word 'rain' is in lines #2 and #3. (First line always starts from zero)

Here is my code so far, but I need help on the algorithm for this.

```
def lineIndex(fName):
    d = {}
    with open(fName, 'r') as f:       

        #algorithm goes here

print(lineIndex('index.txt'))
```

Comment: defaultdict(set) will be useful here found in 'from collections import defaultdict'

Comment: Start by looking up how to iterate over the lines in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first time writing something in Python, but this works:

```
def lineIndex(fName):
    d = {}
    with open(fName, 'r') as f:       
        content = f.readlines()
        lnc = 0
        result = {}
        for line in content:
            line = line.rstrip()
            words = line.split(" ")
            for word in words:
                tmp = result.get(word)
                if tmp is None:
                    result[word] = []
                if lnc not in result[word]:
                    result[word].append(lnc)

            lnc = lnc + 1

        return result

print(lineIndex('index.txt'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am proud that you actually wrote something correct after using Python for the first time! This is correct. I struggled so much when I first learned any computer language.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way using sets, I will give you the exercise on how to do it with a file.

```
In [14]: text = """I have no pride
    ...: I have no shame
    ...: You gotta make it rain
    ...: Make it rain rain rain"""

In [15]:

In [15]: from collections import defaultdict

In [16]: d = defaultdict(set)

In [17]: for i, line in enumerate(text.split('\n')):
    ...:     for each_word in line.split(' '):
    ...:         d[each_word].add(i)
    ...:
    ...:

In [18]: d
Out[18]:
defaultdict(set,
            {'I': {0, 1},
             'Make': {3},
             'You': {2},
             'gotta': {2},
             'have': {0, 1},
             'it': {2, 3},
             'make': {2},
             'no': {0, 1},
             'pride': {0},
             'rain': {2, 3},
             'shame': {1}})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def lineIndex(fName):
    dic = {}
    i=0
    with open(fName, 'r') as f:       
        while True:
            x=f.readline()
            if not x:
                break
            i+=1
            for j in x:
                if j in dic:
                    dic[j].add(i)
                else:
                    dic[j]=set()
                    dic[j].add(i)
    print (dic)

print (lineIndex("index.txt"))
```